# Name of the distribution associated with the square of a cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, statistics, terminology

If $x\mapsto F(x)$ is a cumulative distribution function (c.d.f.), then $x\mapsto (F(x))^2$ is also a c.d.f.

If F is common law, is there a name for the induced transformation?

For example, if $X\sim F$ where $F$ is the c.d.f. of the standard normal, what name would we give to $Y\sim F^2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent with same distribution and CDF $F$, then
\begin{align*}
P(\max(X,Y) \leq z) &= P(X\leq z, Y\leq z) \\
&= P(X\leq z)P(Y\leq z) \\
&= F(z)^2
\end{align*}
Thus the random variable $Z = \max(X,Y)$ has CDF $F^2$. Similarly one can prove that the CDF of $\max(X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots , X_n)$ has CDF $F^n$, whenever $X_1,\dots X_n$ are i.i.d. with CDF $F$.

So for instance a variable $Z$ with CDF $\Phi^2$, where $\Phi$ is the CDF of $N(0,1)$ can be seen as the distribution of the maximum of two independent standard normal variables. (I am unaware wheter this distribution has a particular name.)

The induced transformation of $F \mapsto F^n$ can be viewed as the $n$'th order statistic in an i.i.d. sample of size $n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic .

Comment: After doing a quick google search i found this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173064/what-is-the-distribution-for-the-maximum-minimum-of-two-independent-normal-ran in which it is stated that the maximum of two independent normal distributions becomes a skewed normal distribution. So the distribution does have a particular name.

Comment: Jesus, I'm so dumb. Somehow, I didn't realise it was the distribution of the maximum.
Thanks man.